# orderby in linq to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

```
   AllMovieInfo = from movieInfo in AllMovieInfo
                           from countryMovie in movieInfo.SeenItWantToSeenIt
                           where countryMovie.Status==1
                           select movieInfo;

            var seenitorderby = db.SeenItWantToSeeIt.Where(m => m.Status == 1).GroupBy(m => m.MovieID).Select(g => new  {MovieID =g.Key,count=g.Count()}).OrderBy(o=>o.count);
            List<int> seenItList=seenitorderby.Select(s=>s.MovieID).ToList();
            AllMovieInfo = (from a in AllMovieInfo
                       from s in seenItList
                       where seenItList.Contains(a.MovieID)
                       select a).Distinct();
```

This query is ordering the result according to "AllMovieInfo.MovieID" which is obvious but I have to order the "result" according to the id that comes is  "seenitorderby" eg: seen it orderby may take movieID 2,25,7,14,25 then I need AllMovieInfo according same order as seenitorderby .How can I order the "result" according to "seenitorderby " ?

Comment: Based on your join aren't `AllInfo.ID` and `SeenInfo.ID` the same?

Comment: So what is the `SeenInfo` primary key you wish to order on?

Comment: Note that the fact they're being returned order by `Id` now is pure chance (most likely down to the way the database is implemented). Unless you specifically provide an order, assume results will be random even if they don't appear to be on your dev system

Answer (score 0):

Based on your join aren't AllInfo.ID and SeenInfo.ID the same?

If I'm mistaken the following should do it

```
var result= (from a in AllInfo
             from s in SeenInfo
             where s.ID==a.ID 
             orderby s.ID // <-- this should be the SeenInfo primary key
             select a).Distinct();
```

**UPDATE: Based on question update**

Thanks for the update.  I think I now understand your problem.  Do you wish to order by the count for a particular movie...

```
AllMovieInfo = from movieInfo in AllMovieInfo
               from countryMovie in movieInfo.SeenItWantToSeenIt
               where countryMovie.Status==1
               select movieInfo;

var seenItOrderBy = db.SeenItWantToSeeIt
                      .Where(m => m.Status == 1)
                      .GroupBy(m => m.MovieID)
                      .Select(g => new  { MovieID = g.Key, Count=g.Count()});

var result = (from a in AllMovieInfo
              from s in seenItOrderBy
              where s.MovieID = a.ID
              orderby s.Count
              select a).Distinct();
```

You may be able to simplify this as follows...

*PLEASE NOTE: This is off the top of my head and based on what I believe you are trying to achive in your code, so please take it as such.*

```
var result = db.AllMovieInfo
               // Where someone wants to see it wants to see it
               .Where(mi => mi.SeenItWantToSeeIt.Any(m => m.Status == 1))
               // Order by number of people that have seen or want to see it
               .OrderBy(mi => mi.SeenItWantToSeeIt.Count(m => m.Status == 1));
```

Comment: This will give the same result as your existing code until you change the `orderby` line to be the `SeenInfo` primary key.  Since `SeenInfo.ID` is a foreign key to `AllInfo` they will be the same

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it helps.  PLease bare in mind it makes a fair few assumptionss